# What is wrong with this regex PHP code?

Tags: php, regex

I have a folder that stores some thousands of pictures files.
I want to change the name of each file that matches the condition.
The idea is if the file name has **_10** change to **_ten**, if has **_5** change to **_five**.
So, **xxdf23_10hy.jpg** should be **xxdf23_tenhy.jpg**, **16_5_gt5.jpg** should change to **16_five_gt5.jpg**. But if file mane is **gdjd_7.jpg**, do nothing.

The code is working good, but it is matching the string ".." that should not be matched.

This is the part of the code:

```
$photoPath="../pic/";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($photoPath);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    $filename = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    if(preg_match($filename, "/_10/")){
      //change te name to "_ten"
    }
    elseif(preg_match($filename, "/_5/")){
      //change te name to "_five"
    }
}
```

Something is not good with the way I am using the preg_match function.
But if I try it inside [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/vW2qZ2/1) it works good.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a good example of where you really don't need regexps. Just a simple check if the string contains a substring would do.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen internally, substring uses regexps. So with regexp you save an step. And regexp are powerful, you can make a regexp in this case for bulletproof (actually it doesnt)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I know PHP is silly, but if that's true...

Comment: silly why? Regular expresions are powerful, an PHP too. Maybe you are a Java programmer, that makes ids in html with dots.... LOL

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I don't believe this to be the case, but would like to see if you have documentation on this.  My understanding is that the underlying algorithm that PHP uses is the Sunday algorithm http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/sundayen.htm

Comment: Good information, sorry for the mistake. However, php it's not silly. Maybe some php developers are, but not the language. I hate fanboys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your subject and pattern switched in the preg_match() commands. Try this:

```
if (preg_match("/_10/", $filename)) {
    // more code
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

No need for the overhead of regex here at all. Perhaps simple `glob()` and `str_replace()` would meet your needs.

```
$photoPath="../pic/";

$replacements = array(
    '_5' => '_five',
    '_10' => '_ten'
);

foreach ($replacements as $pattern => $replace) {
    $files = glob($photoPath . '*' . $pattern . '*');
    foreach($files as $file) {
       $old_name = $file;
       $new_name = str_replace($pattern, $replace, $old_name); 
       rename($old_name, $new_name);
    }
}
```

Here we don't even use regex or PHP string searching functionality to find the files we want to change.  We use `glob()` which is basically a direct call to underlying libc `glob()` function and should perform significantly better and with less memory usage than the `DirectoryIterator` with post-filter functionality you are currently using. `DirectoryIterator` is probably overkill here anyway unless you are doing more complex file operations. `glob()` would filter your file names for you, meaning you are not doing useless regex searches against every file contained in `DirectoryIterator` object like you are currently doing.

The actual filepath name change is executed using basic str_replace(). You don't currently show how you are doing this, but I would imagine you would implement something similar or possibly just use `preg_replace()` rather than `preg_match()` if you desire to stick with regex approach.

Comment: This is another nice possiblity too. Thanks

Comment: @zwitterion Thanks. I did add some additional commentary contrasting my approach vs. the DirectoryIterator and regex approach. Hopefully this helps illustrate why I proposed this approach.